# Finite Definition of Span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let S be a finite set of vectors $S\subseteq V$ with a vector space V over a field F. I have two alternate definitions of span(S): $span(S)=\bigcap_{S\subseteq M\subseteq V} M $ and $span(S) = \left \{ \sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda _{i}v_{i}: k\epsilon \mathbb{N}, v_{i}\epsilon S, \lambda _{i}\epsilon F \right \}$. Why are these two definitions equivalent?

Comment: What is your original definition of span?

Comment: One thing I am confused with is that if you let V= $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and let S equal to anything but the null wouldn't that give you just span(S)=S for the first definition? This is obviously not equal to the second definition. Is there an example of a vector space V and S not equal to the null set where the span(S) does not equal S and explain why. I feel as though I am confused with the first definition in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose $M$ denotes a subspace of $V$.

That's because any such $M$ must contain any linear combination of the generators, and conversily the set of these linear combinations *is* a subspace  of $V$.

Comment: One thing I am confused with is that if you let V= $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and let  S equal to anything but the null wouldn't that give you just span(S)=S for the first definition? This is obviously not equal to the second definition. Is there an example of a vector space V and S not equal to the null set where the span(S) does not equal S and explain why. I feel as though I am confused with the first definition in this way.

Comment: No, because such $S$ is *not*  a subspace, and any intersection of subspaces is a subspace. The only subspace containing $S$ is $V$ in this case.

Comment: So if S = { (10, 11), (12, 2)} and V=$ \mathbb{R^{2}}$= {(1,3), (-1, 1), ($\pi$, 4), ...}, wouldn't M be satisfied for { (10, 11), (12, 2) } as well as an infinite number of sets such as { (10, 11), (12, 2), ...}. The intersection of { (10, 11), (12, 2) }$\cap$ { (10, 11), (12, 2), ...}$\cap$...={(10, 11), (12, 2)} correct?

Comment: It would be correct *but* in your context, $M$ is supposed to be a subspace and $S$ is not.